# Elapsed time of unsigned wrapping timer

Tags: math, timer, overflow, underflow

Consider I have a timer that returns a `uint32_t` value (representing a number of ticks), always counts upwards, and wraps to 0 after reaching `UINT32_MAX`.

Suppose I need to take an elapsed time from time `a` to time `b`, and I don't know how high the timer might be initially and whether it will wrap between `a` and `b`.  Both `a` and `b` are type `uint32_t` and get assigned to the timer's return value.

Is it a correct statement that we can take `(uint32_t)(b-a)` to get the elapsed time so long as no more than UINT32_MAX ticks have elapsed — and will it be correct even if the timer wrapped once?  What is the proof for this?

Answer (score 1):

Let N = 2<sup>32</sup>. Let A and B be the timestamps of the start and end *before* wrapping to the [0, N) range, and assume A ≤ B < A + N. Then a = A % N and b = B % N. We are interested in computing the duration D = B - A.

When a ≤ b, it is trivial that D = B - A = b - a.

What about when a > b? Then a ≤ b + N and it must be that D = B - A = b + N - a.

But b - a is of course congruent b + N - a modulo N. Since addition and subtraction between `std::uint32_t` is all modulo N, you can safely compute your answer as `D = b - a`. The subtraction operator between two `std::uint32_t` values is already a `std::uint32_t`, so there's no reason to specify a cast as in `(std::uint32_t)(b - a)`.